# jQuery - RAF animation image scale translate

Tags: jquery, hover, translate-animation, requestanimationframe, scaletransform

I created a little js script in order to scale and translate an image on hover.
I made the scaling animation thanks to RAF in order to make it works in my case. And it's clearly more smooth in Firefox and IE.

However, I have a little difficulty to make it works properly. I want to pan/zoom an image on hover. But I need to add a delay or factor in odered to prevent to show the red background under.

I don't know how to solve my problem...

Here the fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/8hto1e9L/1/

Comment: Tried setting background to transparent at mouseenter event http://fiddle.jshell.net/8hto1e9L/2/ ?

Comment: Thank you for your proposition but the problem is to find a real solution... Not to hide a background. I try to find a mathematical solution, to calculate it in the right way...

Comment: Does **[this](http://fiddle.jshell.net/8hto1e9L/3/)** help?

Comment: Thank you for you proposition but it's still buggy in term of effect. I can't find the right equation.